# Aligning in Relatively Layouts

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have this layout **inside** of a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llWatchItemCommentButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myMasterCat_Item"
        style="@style/DropShadowEffect"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="99"
        android:shadowColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Item"
        android:textColor="#515b61"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bFollowComment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/featured_button_selector"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/comment" />
</LinearLayout>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/myMastCat_Cat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/llWatchItemCommentButton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/llWatchItemCommentButton"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:text="MasterCat"
    android:textColor="#666"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Essentially, if that `TextView` in the Layout becomes two lines, it will overlap with the `TextView positioned below the`LinearLayout`.

Is there an attribute perhaps that could correct this?  As in, I want the bottom `TextView` to be below the entire `LinearLayout` at all times, even if it begins to grow.  Right now, the position appears fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/myMastCat_Cat"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/llWatchItemCommentButton"    //add this line in
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/llWatchItemCommentButton"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/llWatchItemCommentButton"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:text="MasterCat"
android:textColor="#666"
android:textSize="16sp" />
```